# Why do CSS instructions not recognize header classes?

Tags: html, css, html-heading

Why does a CSS file not understand a reference to a header based on its class? One would expect the following two CSS commands to set each line as a different color. Instead, we are presented with unexpected behavior.

```css
h1.red{
    color: red;
}
h1.blue{
    color:blue;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class='red'>This text should be red.</h1>
        <h2 class='blue'>This text should be blue.</h2>
    </body>       
</html>
```

Is there any way to distinguish more than one header tag in CSS?

Comment: Is `h2.blue {
  color: blue;
}` just a typo or the actual issue?  You might use simply `.blue {
  color: blue;
}` instead to avoid the tag change issues.   Red works by the way.

Comment: It is just a typo. I made an obvious mistake. (Syntax error) Should I delete this question?

Comment: I would close it/delete it

Comment: How do I close a question? @MarkSchultheiss

Comment: There should be a "delete" button to remove it which is what I would do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to modify an `<h2>` element with an `h1` selector. Try

```
h1.red{
    color: red;
}
h2.blue{
    color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mistakingly adding an h2 instead of two h1's.